# How to make MVC3 DisplayFor show the value of an Enum's Display-Attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, enums

in a MVC3-Project, I'm using an enum with display-Attributes:

```
public enum Foo {
  [Display(Name = "Undefined")]
  Undef = 0,

  [Display(Name = "Fully colored")]
  Full = 1
}
```

The model class has a property using this enum:

```
public Foo FooProp { get; set; }
```

The view uses the model class and displays the property via

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FooProp)
```

Now, finally, my question:

How can I make .DisplayFor() show the string from the Display-Attribute instead of showing only the enum's value-name? (it should show "Undefined" or "Fully colored", but displaysp "Undef" or "Full").

Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A custom display template might help (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Foo.cshtml`):

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@model Foo

@{
    var field = Model.GetType().GetField(Model.ToString());
    if (field != null)
    {
        var display = ((DisplayAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (display != null)
        {
            @display.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think that should be 'if(display.Name.Length > 0)'. A DisplayAttribute does not have a property Length.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` can return NULL (no attribute present) so you must check that also!

Comment: Can it be a generic enum type template?

Answer (score 0):

### Another Solution

**NOTE:** This code does **not** rely on `@Html.DisplayFor()`

I did it like this...

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Nilhoor.Utility.Extensions
{
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        .
        .
        .

        public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum @enum)
        {
            var memberName = @enum.ToString();
            
            var nameAttribute = @enum.GetType().GetMember(memberName).FirstOrDefault()?.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
            
            return nameAttribute != null 
                ? nameAttribute.GetName() 
                : memberName;
        }
    }
}
```

In x.cshtml

```
@using Nilhoor.Utility.Extensions
.
.
.
<span>Value: </span>
<span>@Model.Type.GetDisplayName()</span>
```