# how to get assigned string values from enum in C#

Tags: c#

I created this enum

```
 public enum Days
    {
        [Display("Monday")]
        Mon,
        [Display("Tuesday")]
        Tue,
        [Display("Wednesday")]
        Wed,
        [Display("Thursday")]
        Thu,
        [Display("Friday")]
        Fri,
        [Display("Satrday")]
        Sat,
    }
```

I want to get the string "Monday". I tried by doing this

```
Console.WriteLine(Days.mon);
```

But is gives me "mon" instead of "Monday".
is there any way to get string Monday?

Comment: Why not use the full name in the Enum itself? Or even better use  System.DayOfWeek instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Display Name Attribute of an Enum member via MVC Razor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've enhanced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172410/1454806) to give you a more fully rounded-out solution, with better semantic syntax.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public static class EnumExtensions {

    // This extension method is broken out so you can use a similar pattern with 
    // other MetaData elements in the future. This is your base method for each.
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
        var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        return (T)attributes[0];
    }

    // This method creates a specific call to the above method, requesting the
    // Description MetaData attribute.
    public static string ToName(this Enum value) {
        var attribute = value.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }

}
```

This solution creates a pair of extension methods on Enum, to allow you to do what you're looking for. I've enhanced your `Enum` code slightly, to use the syntax for the `DisplayAttribute` class of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public enum Days {
        [Display(Name = "Sunday")]
        Sun,
        [Display(Name = "Monday")]
        Mon,
        [Display(Name = "Tuesday")]
        Tue,
        [Display(Name = "Wednesday")]
        Wed,
        [Display(Name = "Thursday")]
        Thu,
        [Display(Name = "Friday")]
        Fri,
        [Display(Name = "Saturday")]
        Sat
    }
```

To use the above extension method, you would now simply call the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(Days.Mon.ToName());
```

or

```
var day = Days.Mon;
Console.WriteLine(day.ToName());
```

Comment: Switching `ToName` so it utilizes `var attribute = value.GetAttribute<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute>();` requires changing the return to `attribute.Name`, so I at least got that far.  What **I'd** like to see is a function that returns some sort of collection (Dictionary, maybe?) that includes key, value pairs for all the items in the `enum` list.  Too much to ask?

Comment: That's a great idea, J.D. I'd love to see it, if you come up with one.

Answer (score 2):

```
var type = typeof(Days);
var memInfo = type.GetMember(Days.Mon.ToString());
var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute),
    false);
var description = ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value) solution.