# MVC EnumDropDownListFor with Enum Display Description attribute as the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have an Enum with Display Description attribute,

```
public enum CSSColours
    {
        [Display(Description = "bg-green")]
        Green,

        [Display(Description = "bg-blue")]
        Blue,
    }
```

Now I want to bind this Enum to a DropDownlist, showing the Enum value (Green, Blue) in the Dropdown item display text and Description as the item Value (bg-green, bg-blue).

When I bind the Dropdown with `EnumDropDownListFor` helper method

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(c => dm.BgColor)
```

It sets the item value to Enum value (0, 1), and couldn't find a way to set the value to Display Description.

How can I set the value to Enum Display Description attribute?

Comment: it's discussed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code

Answer (score 8):

You need to get display name (DisplayAttribute) from Enum, 
Check below Example to set the value of Enum Display Description attribute

Action (binding dropdownlist)

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            var enumDataColours = from CSSColours e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CSSColours))
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = StaticHelper.GetDescriptionOfEnum((CSSColours)e),
                               Name = e.ToString()
                           };
            ViewBag.EnumColoursList = new SelectList(enumDataColours, "ID", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

Helper method GetDescriptionOfEnum to get Description attribute by enum name

```
public static class StaticHelper
    {
        public static string GetDescriptionOfEnum(Enum value)
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            if (!type.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Type '{0}' is not Enum", type));

            var members = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
            if (members.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Member '{0}' not found in type '{1}'", value, type.Name));

            var member = members[0];
            var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("'{0}.{1}' doesn't have DisplayAttribute", type.Name, value));

            var attribute = (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attributes[0];
            return attribute.Description;
        }
    }
```

Razor view

```
@Html.DropDownList("EnumDropDownColours", ViewBag.EnumColoursList as SelectList)
```

Enum

```
public enum CSSColours
    {
        [Display(Description = "bg-green")]
        Green,

        [Display(Description = "bg-blue")]
        Blue,
    }
```

Comment: The only thing I would change in this answer is to change the DropDownList to a DropDownListFor like this:

 '@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CSSColour, ViewBag.CSSColours as SelectList, "Select One")'