# Custom attribute: An attribute argument must be a constant expression

Tags: c#, enums, compiler-errors, custom-attributes

I have defined a custom `enum` `DescriptionAttribute` (see my previous question: [Multiple enum descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32901771/3799847))

```
public class DescriptionWithValueAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    public Decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public DescriptionWithValueAttribute(String description, Decimal value)
        : base(description)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

My `enum` looks like this:

```
public enum DeviceType
{
    [DescriptionWithValueAttribute("Set Top Box", 9.95m)]
    Stb = 1,
}
```

I get the following error when compiling:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

I have also tried: `[DescriptionWithValueAttribute("Set Top Box", (Decimal)9.95)]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Decimals can't be used as attribute parameters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507528/use-decimal-values-as-attribute-params-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my custom `enum` `DescriptionAttribute` to the following:

```
public class DescriptionWithValueAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    public Decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public DescriptionWithValueAttribute(String description, Double value)
        : base(description)
    {
        Value = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    }
}
```

It expects a `Double` then converts to `Decimal`, as I need the final value as a `Decimal`. Works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx):

Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the following types:

- Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
- string
- System.Type
- enums object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
- One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

So, you cant use Decimal. Replace it with float or double. Other way - store value as string and parse it.