# MVC 5 Display attribute issue

Tags: asp.net, enums, asp.net-mvc-5, displayattribute

Enum Class

```
public enum DataReleaseChoice 
{
    Accept, 
    Decline,
    [Display(Name = "Retrieve your application")]
    Continue
}
```

In my view:

```
<input name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.DataReleaseAuthorization)" type="submit" value="@DataReleaseChoice.Accept" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.DataReleaseAuthorization)" type="submit" value="@DataReleaseChoice.Decline" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

All I am trying to do is to add a line for the new "Continue" button, but it should show the DisplayAttributes value ("Retrieve your application")

I've looked at the example provided at [How to get the Display Name Attribute of an Enum member via MVC razor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code) but am struggling to use it in the Razor view. I can display the value in the controller using the following code,

```
var displayAttribute = PAI.Web.Utilities.EnumHelper<DataReleaseChoice>.GetDisplayValue(DataReleaseChoice.Continue);
```

but when I use the same in the razor view as follows,

```
<input name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.DataReleaseAuthorization)" type="submit" value="@PAI.Web.Utilities.EnumHelper<DataReleaseChoice>.GetDisplayValue(DataReleaseChoice.Continue)" class="btn btn-primary" />,
```

I get the error

```
Using the generic type 'EnumHelper<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

I am using MVC 5.2.3, and have read in other forums that MVC 5 supports DisplayAttribute for Enums out of box..  I am struggling to use it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this extension method to get `DisplayName` for enum in Controller or View:

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum value)
    {
        var enumType = value.GetType();
        var enumName = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
        var member = enumType.GetMember(enumName)[0];

        var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DisplayAttribute), false);
        var outString = string.Empty;

        outString = ((DisplayAttribute) attributes[0]).ResourceType != null 
            ? ((DisplayAttribute) attributes[0]).GetName() 
            : ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;

        return outString;
    }
}
```

`<input name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.DataReleaseAuthorization)" type="submit" value="@DataReleaseChoice.Continue.GetDsiplayName()" class="btn btn-primary" />,`