# How to work with display name in enum?

Tags: enums, asp.net-mvc-5

**Question:**

This is my enum and and I am using it in drop-down in MVC5 while creating the project and displaying this status on project details page.But these display name are working properly in drop-down list but in details page it is showing the original value e.g In_Progress.How to work with display name?

**Code:**

```
public enum status
{
[Display(Name="In Progress")]
In_Progrss,

[Display(Name="Completed")]
Completed
}
```

Comment: Are you using `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()`in your view?

Comment: yup.I'm using it in view it is working fine in drop down list but when i'm trying to show the details of project then it is showing In_Progress rather than In Progress. :(

Comment: You will need to create your own extension method to return the value of the `DisplayName` attribute. The [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code) will help you get started (see the `public static string GetDisplayValue(T value)` method in the accepted answer)