# How to bind <select> values to the name of each item in an enum in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an enum of some countries:

```
public enum Countries
{
    USA,
    Canada,
    Mexico,
}
```

I then have a property on my model:

```
[Required]
public string Country { get; set; }
```

In my view I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Countries)) ...)
```

I would like the `value` of each `option` in the generated `select` to be the name of each item from the `Countries` `enum`. By default, the value is a zero-based integer.

Comment: Please don't use asp.net and asp.net-mvc for ASP.NET Core related questions, they are for the old ASP.NET framework/webstack

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The values are zero-based integers because you've asked for an EnumSelectList, which outputs an enum (ie the int values).

Instead, you can get the list of enum names, something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries))) ... )
```

Comment: What would you bind to if your enum looked like this? https://gist.github.com/mariocatch/2f97b5ace087c792de9deed8cdbc7d5e , because binding to the `GetNames` will put the full attribute display name instead of the name of each item.

Comment: @mariocatch not sure what you mean - when I add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `[Display(Name = ..` then use `Enum.GetNames` it still uses the names, not the displayname.  Maybe it's different if you do so in an MVC view, but that sounds unlikely.  Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26455406/2181514

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public CountryFrom CountryFrom { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength (100, ErrorMessage = "Name has to be less then 100 symbols long")]
    public string Region { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Wine> Wines { get; set; }

}

public enum CountryFrom
{
    France, Germany, Italy, Spain, Portugal, UK, India, Bulgaria, Other
}
```

Insert this in the view and don't forget to import the

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CountryFrom" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="CountryFrom" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<CountryFrom>()" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
```

I hope it will help.

This will help you to have a dropdown list with data taken from enumeration and displaying the name if each item.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdVpo.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxDoP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

i found an very useful tagHelpers on Github by Sakura Iris.
https://github.com/sgjsakura/AspNetCore/blob/master/TagHelperDemo.md

You can simply specify the model property, it inherits the source enum and show the Description from a specific Data Annotation. As plus, you can specify the source of values. That's very easy !.

```
@model Project
<select asp-enum-for="AccessType" asp-text-source="Description" asp-value-source="Value"></select>
```