# Creating a enum with a number at the beginning

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following:

```
public enum Size
{
    XXS,
    XS,
    S,
    M,
    L,
    XL,
    1XL, 
    2XL, 
    3XL, 
    4XL, 
    5XL, 
    6XL
}
```

The enum is for a DB and I need it to go into the DB in this format (nvarchar), I have not created this DB table.

> Error 30  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

I know it is because there is a number at the beginning, is there anyway round this, other than doing a switch statement or something?

UPDATE:

This is for a Google Feed, they require the values to be provided as below, this is not our naming convention

Answer (score 3):

C# identifier names cannot begin with numerics. How about rendering the numbers as words? XL, TwoXL, ThreeXL, FourXL and so on?

Comment: Also, your naming convention in this enum is inconsistent. Why is it XXS but 2XL?

Comment: This is for a Google Feed, this is not our naming convention

Comment: I would need to do some sort of conversion to get the value Google requires

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define an identifier name starts with a `digit`, first character must be a letter or an underscore.Here You are trying to overwrite the basic rule for defining an identifier. Let me remind you the rules once again:

- An identifier is a sequence of letters,digits and underscore.
- The **first character** Must be either a letter or an underscore
- Keywords cannot be used as an identifiers, since it is reserved by the language compiler.

The Possible declarations for you:

**Start with an underscore**

```
public enum Size
{
    _XXS,           
    _1XL,
}
```

**Use words instead for digits**

```
public enum Size
{
    _XXS,           
    oneXL,
}
```

Comment: I would still require to do a removal of the _ before inserting into the DB

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, maybe you can work around this issue with DataAnnotations. See this solution:
[How to get the Display Name Attribute of an Enum member via MVC razor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code)

Comment: I think I need to use the 'Description'?

Comment: You need this for each enum value you declare. `[Display(Name = "3XL")]` for for example ThreeXL. In the linked question you can see how to read it out.