# cant get Enum Display Name property in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have an enum with Display(Name=) that I wish to display in a Razor view but I'm getting only the value.

```
 public enum Gender
 {
    [Display(Name = "Man woman")]
    EveryOne = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Man")]
    Man = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Woman")]
    Woman = 2
 }
```

Razor:

```
 Is for: @Model.LectureGig.Gender
```

The Html results are:

> Is for: Everyone

Instead of:

> Is for: Man woman

Comment: You have to get the attribute value yourself - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

like this:

```
    public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                        .GetName();
    }
}
```

& the view :

```
@Model.LectureGig.Gender.GetDisplayName()
```

Comment: this works; Just need to handle enum that has no Display attribute