# How to display the name of enum display attribute

Tags: c#, enums

This is my enum.

```
public enum ContractType
{
    [Display(Name = "Permanent")]
    Permanent= 1,

    [Display(Name = "Part Time")]
    PartTime= 2,

}
```

I try to get display name using below code.

```
 string x = Enum.GetName(typeof(ContractType), 2);
```

But it is return "**PartTime**" always. Actually I want to get the name of display attribute. 
For above example x should be assigned **Part Time**

I saw there are solutions which having huge code. Doesn't this have a simple/one line solution?

Please show me a direction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code

Answer (score 26):

Given an enum

```
public enum ContractType
{
   [Display(Name = "Permanent")]
   Permanent= 1,

   [Display(Name = "Part Time")]
   PartTime //Automatically 2 you dont need to specify
}
```

Custom method to get the data annotation display name.

```
//This is a extension class of enum
public static string GetEnumDisplayName(this Enum enumType)
{
    return enumType.GetType().GetMember(enumType.ToString())
                   .First()
                   .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                   .Name;
}
```

Calling GetDisplayName()

```
ContractType.Permanent.GetEnumDisplayName();
```

Hope this helps :)