# How to get display value from enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I am getting my enum value like so:

```
location = Enum.GetName(typeof(Locations), (Locations)record.Friday);
```

And here is my enum:

```
    public enum Locations
    {
        [Display(Name = "Unspecified")]
        Unspecified = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Sick Leave")]
        sick = 1,
        [Display(Name = "On Holiday")]
        hol = 2
    }
```

Currently I am getting back hol instead of On Holiday

Comment: Doesn't work.  GetDisplayName doesn't show in intelisense

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40995755/284240 (if an extenion is not shown then you haven't added `using YourExtensionClass;`)