# Cannot convert from string to class

Tags: c#, string, constants

I created the below class with constant properties so I can use it as sort of enum.

```
public class Interval
{
  public const string FiveMinutes = "5m";
  public const string FifteenMinnutes = "15m";
  public const string OneDay = "1d";
  public const string OneWeek = "1wk";
  public const string OneMonth = "1mo";
}
```

The content of the method expects `Interval`.

```
public IRestResponse GetSpark(string Symbol, Interval Interval)
        {
  var url = $"https://...?interval={Interval}";
  return RestAPI.RestCall(url);
}
```

When using `Interval.OneWeek` I get the error 'CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'class.Enum.Interval'.'

```
var foo = new fooClass();
var fooMethod = fooClass.GetInfo("Example", Interval.OneWeek);
```

Why do I get this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you show the code for _fooClass.GetInfo_? The error talks about an enum involved but I can't see anywhere an enum here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the call is actually:

```
fooClass.GetSpark("Example", Interval.OneWeek);
```

You're calling this method with two strings as arguments: "Example" and "1wk" (the const string defined in Interval). The GetSpark method actually requires a string and an Interval class, which is not what you're supplying.

So rewrite your GetSpark method to:

```
public IRestResponse GetSpark(string symbol, string interval)
{
  var url = $"https://...?interval={interval}";
  return RestAPI.RestCall(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Note.**
*There are inconsistencies in your question (the method name in the second code snippet is `GetSpark`, but you call `GetInfo` in the third snippet)*

The method expects the class `Interval`, but you're only passing in the `string` value constant of `Interval`. Either change the method signature to accept a `string` instead of an `Interval`

```
public IRestResponse GetSpark(string Symbol, string Interval)
```

Or replace `Interval` with an `enum`

```
public enum Interval
{
    [Display(Name = "5m")]
    FiveMinutes,
    [Display(Name = "15m")]
    FifteenMinutes,
    [Display(Name = "1d")]
    OneDay,
    [Display(Name = "1wk")]
    OneWeek,
    [Display(Name = "1mo")]
    OneMonth,
}
```

You can use this extension method to retrieve the Display Names (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995593/how-to-display-the-name-of-enum-display-attribute)):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetEnumDisplayName(this Enum enumType)
    {
        return enumType.GetType().GetMember(enumType.ToString())
            .First()
            .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
            .Name;
    }
}
```

And replace the first line with this:

```
var url = $"https://...?interval={Interval.GetEnumDisplayName()}";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!