# How to add element to enum with name (default) in MVC C#

Tags: c#, enums, default

Can I in MVC C# add an element to enum with name (default)?

```
public enum Errs
{
    default, primary, success, info, warning, danger
}
```

I received this error:
Identifier expected; 'default' is a keyword

Comment: You can add an @ before default. But I advise you to use Pascal case. in your case: Default, Primary

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `@` syntax for using reserved words as identifiers:

```
public enum Errs
{
    @default, primary, success, info, warning, danger
}
```

However, I would recommend using some other name that is not a C# keyword, and add `[DisplayName]` attribute:

```
public enum Errs
{
    [DisplayName(Name="default")]
    Default,
    [DisplayName(Name="primary")]
    Primary,
    [DisplayName(Name="success")]
    Success,
    [DisplayName(Name="info")]
    Info,
    [DisplayName(Name="warning")]
    Warning,
    [DisplayName(Name="danger")]
    Danger
}
```

Check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13099834/335858) if you need to obtain string names from `DisplayName`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [AliJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3209317/alijp)

I Modified my code as:

```
public enum Errs
{
    Default = 0,
    Primary = 1,
    Success = 2,
    Info = 3,
    Warning = 4,
    Danger = 5,
}

var messageKind = Errs.Danger.ToString().ToLower();
```