# Best practice for passing an enum list to an external JS file? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I currently have a working setup but I would like to know if there is a better implementation.

I have a Genre.cs enum in `~/Models/Genre.cs`
Which is passed to the view in a view model:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    MusicFileCreateViewModel musicFileCreateViewModel = new MusicFileCreateViewModel
    {
        Genres = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Genre)), // This is a string[]
        // ...
    };
    return View(musicFileCreateViewModel);
}
```

Which is then handled in the view and used in the `~/js/musicFileList.js` file

```
@model MusicFileCreateViewModel
// ...

<script>
    var Genres = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Genres));
</script>
<script src="~/js/musicFileList.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to improve this setup? Also, is it possible to get the enum display names instead of the actual names?

Comment: If you are not using frontend technologies, such as angular, this setup is ok. When using angular, you could create an API method that would prepare the data structures needed for the form.

Comment: Hi, @TyGuy96, I already post the code to solve your question. It works on me. If the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To improve this setup

I agree with @Martin Staufcik, use a api to obtain enum data.

1. Creat new `action` to get genres

   ```
       [Route("/genres")]
       public IList<string> GetGenres()
       {
           return EnumHelper<Genre>.GetDisplayValues(Genre.Rock);
       }
   ```
2. add `js` to request `genres`

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.post("/genres", null, function (data, status) {
              //data : ROCK, ELECTRONIC, SOUL, FUNK, COUNTRY
              alert(data[1]);//ELECTRONIC
        });
    </script>
   ```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

> Is it possible to get the enum display names instead of the actual names?

**(1) Import `EnumHelper` to get Enum `display names`**
EnumHelper.cs

```
public static class EnumHelper<T>
{
    public static IList<T> GetValues(Enum value)
    {
        var enumValues = new List<T>();

        foreach (FieldInfo fi in value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            enumValues.Add((T)Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), fi.Name, false));
        }
        return enumValues;
    }

    public static T Parse(string value)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }

    public static IList<string> GetNames(Enum value)
    {
        return value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Select(fi => fi.Name).ToList();
    }

    public static IList<string> GetDisplayValues(Enum value)
    {
        return GetNames(value).Select(obj => GetDisplayValue(Parse(obj))).ToList();
    }

    private static string lookupResource(Type resourceManagerProvider, string resourceKey)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo staticProperty in resourceManagerProvider.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (staticProperty.PropertyType == typeof(System.Resources.ResourceManager))
            {
                System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceManager = (System.Resources.ResourceManager)staticProperty.GetValue(null, null);
                return resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
            }
        }

        return resourceKey; // Fallback with the key name
    }

    public static string GetDisplayValue(T value)
    {
        var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        var descriptionAttributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) as DisplayAttribute[];

        if (descriptionAttributes[0].ResourceType != null)
            return lookupResource(descriptionAttributes[0].ResourceType, descriptionAttributes[0].Name);

        if (descriptionAttributes == null) return string.Empty;
        return (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0) ? descriptionAttributes[0].Name : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

**(2) Add `Genres` to MusicFileCreateViewModel model**
MusicFileCreateViewModel.cs

```
namespace EnumApplication.Models
{
    public enum Genre
    {
        [Display(Name = "ROCK")]
        Rock,
        [Display(Name = "ELECTRONIC")]
        Electronic,
        [Display(Name = "SOUL")]
        Soul,
        [Display(Name = "FUNK")]
        Funk,
        [Display(Name = "COUNTRY")]
        Country

    }
    public class MusicFileCreateViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**(3) Set Enum names to `Genres` by using `EnumHelper`**
Index action in controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            MusicFileCreateViewModel musicFileCreateViewModel = new MusicFileCreateViewModel
            {
                Genres = EnumHelper<Genre>.GetDisplayValues(Genre.Rock),// This is a string[]
                                                                                  // ...
            };

            return View(musicFileCreateViewModel);
        }
```

**(4) Json Serialize**
Index.cshtml

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var value in Model.Genres)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayName(value)</li>
    }
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
function Fn() {
    var Genres = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Genres));

}
</script>
```

Screenshots of Test:
[image]

[EnumHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code) coded by @Hrvoje Stanisic

Comment: In your `$.post("/genres", null, function (data)` function, I am getting "'data' does not exist in the current context" when being passed to the SerializeObject function. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, sorry, my fault, No need to SerializeObject again, it's already serialized. I already update my codes and please try again. :D