# Enum casting in .ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete record from the database using modals, jQuery and javascript but when popup shows I am getting undefined for `Gender`. How can I represent the value of my enum into a new `<td>`?

```js
var deleteBtn = null;

function deleteLeague(leagueId, btn) {
  deleteBtn = btn;
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("DeleteLeague", "League")",
    data: {
      id: leagueId
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#leagueTBody").html("");
      $("#leagueId").val(leagueId);
      $("#leagueTBody").append("<tr><td>" + data.id + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + data.leagueType + "</td>" +
        " <td> " + data.season.name + "</td>" + " <td> " + data.gender + "</td>" + " <td> " +
        data.note + "</td>" +
        "</tr >");
    },
    error: function(req, status, error) {
      ajaxErrorHandlingAlert("error", req.status);
    }
  });
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum Gender
{
  [Display(Name = "Машки")] Male,
  [Display(Name = "Женски")] Female
}
```

It should be `Male` or `Female` in the `Gender` column.

[image]

Comment: I would console.log(data) and see what it contains, does it contain gender or?

Comment: Where should I insert console.log(data)

Comment: The issue seems to be with the data coming back from your AJAX call to `/league/deleteleague`. Can you show us that code. Also note that if you were to follow REST API guidelines, then that call should be making a `DELETE` request to `/league/{id}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I saw my mistake, I wrote ```data.gender``` instead of ```data.genderType``` but now I am getting only ```int``` value. How to cast it into string?

Comment: In your C# logic: `yourClass.Gender.ToString()`, or if you want to get the value from the `Display` attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13099834/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in my controller ?

Comment: If that's where the code is that creates the response, then yeah