# How to get Enum display name

Tags: c#

I have an emun defined as in the sample below.

```
 public enum SampleEnum : int
{
    [Display(Name = "One")]
    Test_One = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Two")]
    Test_Two = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Three")]
    Test_Three = 3

}
```

In the below line of code, how can get the Display instead name?

```
   var displayName = Enum.GetName(typeof(SampleEnum ), 2);
```

In the above line, i would like to get **Two** instead of **Test_Two**

Comment: You mean something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26455406/5767872

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create Extension method for the same.

```
   public static class EnumExtensions
      {
        public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
        {
          return enumValue.GetType()
            .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
            .First()
            .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
            ?.GetName();
        }
      }
```

https://dnilvincent.com/blog/posts/how-to-get-enum-display-name-in-csharp-net