# How to Display the name of a enum not the id in cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, enums

I have a enum like this:

```html
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace eVote.Data.Enums
{
    public enum Positions
    {
        CEO =1,
        ProductManager,
         CTO,
         SalesManager,
        FinanceManager,
         HR,
        Accountant


    }
}
```

When i use this enum in a AddAsync function i use like this:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="position">Function </label>
        <select asp-for="position" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Positions>()" asp-for="position"></select>
       
    </div>
```

But, when i go to index, the position displayed is the id of position

```html
<td>@candidate.position</td>
```

Any thoughts??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test with following code,and it can work:

Model:

```
public class TestModel {
      
        public Positions position { get; set; }
    }
    public enum Positions
    {
        CEO = 1,
        ProductManager,
        CTO,
        SalesManager,
        FinanceManager,
        HR,
        Accountant


    }
```

action:

```
 public IActionResult B()
        {

            return View(new TestModel {  position=Positions.CEO });


        }
```

View:

```
@model TestModel 
<h1>@Model.position</h1>
```

result:

[image]

If it still doesn't work,try to check the type of `position`.

Comment: Yes, i needed to make the position attribute of type Positions and update the database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the name of an enum value as a string, you have to call the `ToString()` method on the value.

```cs
enum UserRole {
   User,
   Admin
}

Console.WriteLine(UserRole.User.ToString());
```

This will print `User`.

Comment: read the question again. I want to get the name in HTML not in the Console.

Comment: If you don't know how to go from this code to your implementation, then I'd suggest you'd look at a tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done, added `Display(Name...` [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code)

```
public enum Positions
{
    [Display(Name = "CEO")]
    CEO,
    [Display(Name = "ProductManager")]
    ProductManager,
    [Display(Name = "CTO")]
     CTO,
     [Display(Name = "SalesManager")]
     SalesManager,
     [Display(Name = "FinanceManager")]
    FinanceManager,
    [Display(Name = "HR")]
     HR,
     [Display(Name = "Accountant")]
    Accountant
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Still it shows me the id

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `ToString()` method to format it as a string.

```
<td>@candidate.position.ToString()</td>
```

Comment: Not working.     <td>@candidate.position.ToString()</td>. It s still show me the id

Comment: Then what is the type of the variable `position`? If I have an enum `enum MyType { A, B, C }` and print a member of it `Console.WriteLine(MyType.A.ToString());` it prints `A`.